# Probabilty problem related to two cabinets containing gold and silver coins.

Tags: probability

**Each of the two cabinets has 3 drawers. Cabinet I contains a gold coin in each drawer and cabinet II contains a gold coin in one of its drawers and a silver coin in the other. A cabinet is randomly selected ,one of its drawers is opened and a gold coin is found. Find the probability that there is a gold coin in the other drawer.**

The answer given in book is 3/4
[image: THIS IS WHAT I HAVE DONE]

Comment: The problem says each cabinet has three drawers, then for cabinet two talks of one drawer and the other.  Does it have an empty drawer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea what $C$ is doing there. There is no need to specify the event that a cabinet is chosen, as that event is guaranteed to happen, and doesn't affect any probabilities.

Try using the events $L$ for picking the left cabinet and $G$ for picking a gold drawer. You want $$P(L\mid G)=\frac{P(L\cap G)}{P(G)}$$ $P(L\cap G)=P(L)$ is immediately seen to be $\frac12$, while $P(G)$ takes some calculation.

Alternately, as long as we are in land the land of assuming that $G$ occurs, there are $4$ equally likely possibilities. Three of them are in the all-gold cabinet and one isn't.

Comment: I am a big fan of the alternative route. Nice to see it mentioned here.

Comment: @drhab It's very simple and immediate. But it runs into trouble with human intuition, somewhat like Monty Hall. So I like it, but it's often insufficient for pedagogical purposes. Thus I started with the rote calculation.

Comment: I am not getting it . please can you explain a bit further? What is ".|G" - land can you please say and we are to find the probability of getting a gold coin in the other drawer. I can't get the situation of problem. Probably knowing that would help me to find out why required answer is P(L|G). @Arthur

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh What I mean by "${}\cdot {}\mid G$"-land is that there are four golden drawers, and they are all equally likely to have been picked. Three of them are in the golden cabinet. So in $\frac34$ of all cases where we pick a golden drawer (i.e. we are interested in the conditional that $G$ has ocurred, in other words every event is of the type "$\text{something}{}\mid G$"), we are in the golden cabinet.

Comment: Can u explain me the problem as well please

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh I am uncertain as to what you think is unclear. Can you be a bit more specific than "the problem"?

Comment: Means 'the gold coin in the other drawer'

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh I think it's a typo, and they mean "the other drawers [of the selected cabinet]".

Answer (score 2):

I assume the second cabinet also has an empty drawer to make three.  In that case, we are equally likely to select each drawer.  There are six possibilities, but we discard the two where we get the silver and nothing. leaving four.  Three of them have a gold coin in another drawer, so the chance is $\frac 34$.

A more careful approach is that there is $\frac 12$ chance we choose the first cabinet.  In that case we surely choose a gold coin and have another in another drawer.  There is $\frac 16$ chance we choose the second cabinet and then the gold drawer.  Here we do not have another gold coin, so the chance we have another gold coin given that we found one in the first drawer is $$\frac {\frac 12}{\frac 12+\frac 16}=\frac 34$$